# Silverlight InitializeComponent

Tags: c#, silverlight

Are silverlight pages initialized every time they are called? InitializeComponent();
Once they are called is this stored in memory?

If they are Initiallzed everytime they are called is there a way to check to see if it has already been rendered so as to bypass the rendering of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A page is an object like any other - if you create one, then navigate to a different page, the original is no longer referenced and becomes eligible for garbage collection. If you visit the page again, you get an all-new instance.

You asked this question in terms of a preconceived solution (avoid page rendering). What is the underlying issue that led you to consider this approach?

Comment: I have a silverlight application that is using some telerik controls. we have incorporated some MVVM into a standard Silverlight Business Application. When you click the about link in this application the about page will render some docks panels and some ribbons..when you leave and come back it renders them again so now i have two tabs that are the same..thanks for helping if possible

Comment: @gevjen: What happens when you click the about button? Does it navigate to a new page within a frame from the Silverlight Navigation Controls? Also, can you give some context on what you mean by "I have two tabs that are the same". I am unsure how that relates to the navigation.

Comment: So when i clicked About it would take me that page. where i would register some telerik controls Dockpanel and ribbon button. I have a General Tab on the ribbon...when i would go from About to Home and back to About I would have two tabs that say General...but I just figured this out..I put a static bool at the class level and after i do the dockpanel and before I create the ribbon i check that bool. and it works! i appreciate the help though.